# SingleEmailMessage sending isn't working when called from Unit Test

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have the following code:

```
    public class OrderRequestCreationEmails {
    public static void sendMail()
    { 
        Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(2);
        Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
        String[] toAddresses = new String[] {'dgriff@varonis.com'}; 

        mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

        mail.setReplyTo('dgriff@varonis.com');

        mail.setSenderDisplayName('Mail Test');

        mail.setSubject('Success! Mail Sent');

        mail.setBccSender(false);
        mail.setPlainTextBody('BODY');

        Messaging.sendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail });
    }
}
```

I tried to call this function from a test as such: (I know its not an actual test, its just to see if I receive a mail).

```
@isTest
private class CreationEmailsTest {
    @isTest private static void sendMailTest() {
        OrderRequestCreationEmails.sendMail();
    }
}
```

And I haven't received the mail, no idea why?

It's an example I took from the salesforce developer guide. couldn't find any answers online...

FYI - deliverability in the sandbox is turned on, and test deliverability works

Comment: Test classes / methods do not send emails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unit tests have no "side effects," because the entire transaction is rolled back at the end of the test. Absolutely nothing you do within the test will have any effect in the "real world." This includes creating, modifying, or deleting records, calling out to external systems, sending emails, leaving scheduled jobs in any of the relevant queues, etc. If you want to really send an email, you need to call it from live code, such as execute anonymous or the API. That said, the point of a unit test is to make sure the code works; if your unit test passes, as written, it means that the email *would* have been sent out if it had not been a unit test.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation.
how do you execute anonymous in eclipse? or is it only in the developer console?

Comment: @D.Griff Right-click on your project, choose Force.com > Execute Anonymous..., and you can run your code there.

Answer (score 0):

To test if this method is working, you can execute this code in an anonymous window.

```
OrderRequestCreationEmails.sendMail();
```

Comment: in the developer console, or its possible via eclipse as well?

Comment: Yes, you can run it via both developer console and Eclipse.

Comment: In eclipse, right click on the Force.com project. Select Force.com > Execute Anonymous